# Thread-safe and queued tasks in Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have few questions. As far as I know, every request to a container becomes a `HttpServletRequest`. More request-> more instances of `HttpServletRequest`. Then, when a request object calls a servlet called 'abc', an instance of 'abc' servlet is created. Let's say same time 3 requests come to 'abc' servlet ,then
 **(1)** I want to know ,does it mean, 3 instances of 'abc' servlet per each request are created? or requests are queued till one request to the servlet is done.

Then let's say,3 request to 'abc' servlet do some database processes which could be insertions and retrieves *at the same time*. Then
**(2)** does one request should be in the queue until other request's servelt completes the task (synchronize)or all servelets do their DB task as multi threads as seperate tasks(not sinchronized) ?
**(3).** If they work as not synchronized, how can we make those tasks synchronized (lets say, only one particular task-save some thing to DB) and queued ? to do so, is it better to implement the servlet `SingleThreadModel` or use a method which is in a class created according to singleton pattern ?  Then how it affect to the performance of the container?

In short,how can we run a particular task synchronized for all requests ?

I read [this](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1015) as well. That article says about servlets. Lets say the task of a servlet is handed over to another class, then I would like to know how about using singleton pattern on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A container may create a pool of servlet instances (an excerpt from a servlet spec below explains the details). It may use three different instances for three concurrent requests or may use one for all three. Your servlets thus need to be thread safe and shouldn't have state in their member variables. The `SingleThreadModel` marker interface will signal to container not to use same instance of the servlet for more than one concurrent request (thus making your servlet thread-safe) but it won't prevent the container from creating multiple instances and using them simultaneously. makes sense? if your operation requires synchronization then you handle it in your Model classes, not your Controller. So basically synchronize (or queue things up) elsewhere is the answer. Let the servlets take the command and just run with it without putting too much thoughts into the process.

**UPDATE**. A very basic example of explicit operation synchronization for your case (not that I like it, just to illustrate the point) would be to have a singleton service handling your operation with its main `do()` method declared as `synchronized`. Ideally, though, you would delegate database concurrency to your database and persistence layer (transactions, optimistic concurrency).

**CORRECTION** as per the [servlets spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/first/jsr053/servlet23_PFD.pdf):

```
In the default case of a servlet not implementing SingleThreadModel and not hosted in a
distributed environment, the servlet container must use only one instance of a servlet class
per servlet definition.
In the case of a servlet that implements the SingleThreadModel interface, the servlet
container may instantiate multiple instances of that servlet so that it can handle a heavy
request load while still serializing requests to a single instance.
```

With that said, you would have only one instance of your servlet unless you use that single thread model marker.

Comment: Thanks. Now little bit confused. as per the servlets spec, if  SingleThreadModel is not implemented, then there is no pool of servlet instances ?  Also if we don't implement any explicity operations, might requests be queued till first request's task is completed by the servlet implicitly ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, servlet3.0 deprecated SingleThreadModel.

Comment: @AashMaharoon, that is correct, if SingleThreadModel is not implemented there will be only one instances which serves all requests.

Comment: Thanks. Then requests are queued till earlier request's task is done by the servlet?

Comment: @AashMaharoon, I would imagine so assuming you synchronized on it. The thread to first acquire the monitor would keep it until it's done and all other threads (= requests) will have to wait. Like thinksteep suggested in his answer it's a NOT recommended practice. You can very easy run out of threads if you have just enough concurrent requests and your processing takes just long enough. I recommend you find a better place to handle concurrency.

Comment: @PavelVeller, Thank you very much. Would you explain more this statement' I recommend you find a better place to handle concurrency' please .

Comment: like I recommended in my original answer you could take it into your services layer to keep your controller focused on doing its own thing. Not sure if you're using Spring or any other "container" to manage your services but you can imagine a singleton class with a do() method that is declared synchronized. Your servlet would then delegate whatever it needs to do to the services. Ideally though you would do it even further down the stack. If you worry about concurrent updates to your database then maybe transactions and proper concurrency control is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
1) No, only instance of servlet exists per server
2) No, each request is separate thread
```

Your server could shouldn't contain any instance variables (or) static variables, then synchronization won't be any issue because each thread will have it's own copy of local variables and execution sequence.

3) You can make servlet synchronized by prefixing synchronized the doGet(), doPost() methods are with the help of synch block. But it is bad practice.

Refer this [SO Wiki link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for complete discussion.

Answer (score 0):

to synchronize a particular task, Let me suggest 2 ways.

1. use java `synchronized` block. You should consider what object is suitable for the lock object.
2. use database lock. Such as `select * from xxx for update`

Comment: Thank. Would you explain more about your 2nd suggestion?